# Access VBA Pop Up Sub Form for Submission of Entries

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's what I've got:
I have an Access form that accepts entries, and places them into a table when the ENTER button is clicked.  At the moment, I have a popup message box that comes up when the button is clicked, asking them to confirm that their entries are ok (your standard pop up box, with OK and CANCEL options).  This popup box comes up right in the middle of the data that the user has entered, and is pretty inconvenient for the user to deal with.

Instead of this popup message box, I came up with the idea of using a pop-up SUB-FORM, that would lie invisible just under the ENTER button, and would come up visible when ENTER is clicked. (Same options as the message box, etc, just different placement.  Making the "physical" subform design was a no brainer).  Since this is a new form/subform, how would I code this in order to make it work like the message box did?  The old code won't work.  This is the best idea I could come up with.  If there's an even better way to accomplish this, I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: Create a normal form, set its popup and modal properties to yes, move it when loads with `DoCmd.MoveSize` and handle the OK - Cancel button events. Plenty of examples on the internet to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an atypical approach, but not necessarily a wrong one. I don't see  why you would need the overhead of a sub_form though. Maybe just create a normal form (modal, no menu controls, no borders, etc., whatever looks pleasing to you) to serve as your Confirm Dialog, use a DoCmd.OpenForm from your Save button to open in (with modal attribute set), and then a DoCmd.MoveSize to move it, with parameters that are derived from the position of your button.

```
DoCmd.MoveSize cmdSaveButton.Left + cmdSaveButton.Height + 10, etc.
```

The Primary Save can happen from the Popup form calling a method in the originating form, and then closing itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-movesize-method-access

Or use the form itself:

```
Form.Move Left:=11500, Top:=6500, Width:=7000, Height:=6000
```

Comment: This seems to be the way to go.  Atypical, as you said, yes.  But if it's effective, I'm good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend, if you feel it necessary to go this route, that you employ the use of a modal pop-up form, whose coordinates I believe you can specify, so that it opens in a particular area. There may be nuances depending upon user screen resolution, but I'm pretty sure this will solve your problem. The subform solution you propose sounds very rickety.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function found in:

> http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/define-a-position-of-messagebox.shtml

```
Option Explicit

' Import
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, _
     ByVal lpfn As Long, _
     ByVal hmod As Long, _
     ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
     ByVal x As Long, _
     ByVal y As Long, _
     ByVal cx As Long, _
     ByVal cy As Long, _
     ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

' Handle to the Hook procedure
Private hHook As Long

' Position
Private msgbox_x As Long
Private msgbox_y As Long

' Hook type
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5

' SetWindowPos Flags
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1      ' Retains the current size
Private Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4    ' Retains the current Z order

Sub TestMsgBox()
    MsgBoxPos "Set non-Center Position", _
              vbOKOnly, _
              "Message Box Hooking", _
              400, 300
End Sub

Public Sub MsgBoxPos(strPromt As String, _
              vbButtons As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
              strTitle As String, _
              xPos As Long, _
              yPos As Long)

    ' Store position
    msgbox_x = xPos
    msgbox_y = yPos

    ' Set Hook
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _
                              AddressOf MsgBoxHookProc, _
                              0, _
                              GetCurrentThreadId)

    ' Run MessageBox
    MsgBox strPromt, vbButtons, strTitle
End Sub

Private Function MsgBoxHookProc(ByVal lMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    If lMsg = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        ' Change position
        SetWindowPos wParam, 0, msgbox_x, msgbox_y, _
                     0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE + SWP_NOZORDER

        ' Release the Hook
        UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
    End If

    MsgBoxHookProc = False
End Function
```